# Caractère/Ponctuation inconnu sur les digrammes "ct" et "st"

Tags: france

Je suis actuellement en train de lire en édition de poche "le Comte de Monte-Cristo". J'ai remarqué quelques subtilités calligraphiques que je prenais au début pour des défauts d'impression. Il s'agit d'un genre d'accent faisant apparemment office de liaison entre les caractères **c** & **t** ainsi que **s** & **t** (je ne crois pas l'avoir rencontré sur d'autres digrammes).

Voyez sur l'illustration "Une bonne a**ct**ion **st**érile" :

[image]

S'agit-il de reliquats d'anciens français ? Est-ce que "ct" et "st" se prononçaient différemment autrefois ?

---

*J'ai conscience que le titre n'image pas bien ma question, si vous avez des suggestions je suis preneur.*

Comment: Sur le même sujet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421775

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rien à voir avec la prononciation ni forcément la langue française : il s'agit de l'esthétique et ça s'appelle *une ligature*.

> Des ligatures du type de *ct* [...] sont purement esthétiques et,
> sûrement, imitent la graphie manuscrite cursive.

Source : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(%C3%A9criture)